# Set initial keyboard focus in Controls.ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a window with a single ListView:

[image: Initial screen]

It looks as if the focus is on the first element in the list. When I press <kbd>Down</kbd>, I expect the focus to move to the second line, but it stays at this element. The dashed border moves though, from the whole list to the first list item:

[image: After pressing Tab]

At this point, pressing <kbd>Down</kbd> moves the focus down as expected.

I already did a bit of research on how to get the keyboard focus right from the beginning, but I didn't succeed. In the properties of a `ListView`, there are `AnchorItem` and `FocusedInfo`, which both look promising, but they are not directly accessible, so I don't know the correct way to set them.

Here is my current XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="CSharp_Playground.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CSharp_Playground"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:Model />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <ListView Name="Persons" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" SelectionMode="Single" />
</Window>
```

And the corresponding C# code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace CSharp_Playground
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Persons.SelectedIndex = 0;
            Persons.Focus();
        }
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> Persons { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>(new []{"1","2","3"});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick seems to be to explicitly set the focus to the item container of the first item in the ListView. I found a good explanation [here](https://cytivrat.blogspot.com/2011/05/selecting-first-item-in-wpf-listview.html).

Short summary of that blog post:

Because the items aren't available directly after creating the ListView focusing has to happen after all items are generated in the background. So, attach to the `StatusChanged` event of the `ItemContainerGenerator`:

```
Persons.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
```

And in the event handler, set the focus after everything has finished generating:

```
private void ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Persons.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
   {
       int index = Persons.SelectedIndex;
       if (index >= 0)
           ((ListViewItem)Persons.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index)).Focus();
   }
}
```

This solution isn't as simple as I hoped it would be but it worked for me.